# Calculate maximal volume between lines from array in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

here my array

```
my.array=structure(list(var1 = 1L, var2 = 8L, var3 = 6L, var4 = 2L, var5 = 5L, 
    var6 = 4L, var7 = 8L, var8 = 3L, var9 = 7L), .Names = c("var1", 
"var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", "var8", "var9"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

in the histogram chart, this array has the form of lines (sorry, I drew in the paint)

[image]

How find two lines, between which a maximum volume of anything could put (for example water)

By blue color,  I painted the water in the tank.
Visually, I see that the maximum volume at `7 point` along the `y axis` between lines `2 and 9 of x asis`. (7*7=49). Because `9 line`  has last `point on 7` of y axis but `line two` has last `point 8 on y asis`, forming as much as possible filled volume,forming a long straight line with max volume.

How can i calculate such result by my array in R, and not manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by defining your variable names as numeric x-positions and coupling that with the y-positions.

```
df <- data.frame(x = seq_along(my.array),
                 y = t(my.array))
```

Then we would want to compare every row in that data.frame with every other row of the data.frame, so we'll make an index for what rows we will be comparing. I've taken the names of `my.array` because they have become the rownames of `df`, so they can be used as indices.

```
idx <- t(combn(names(my.array), 2))
```

Next, I would loop over the rows of the indices, look up the associated variables and do the calculations. The width of the area you've indicated in blue is the absolute difference in x positions and the height of the area is the minimum of the two y positions.

```
area <- apply(idx, 1, function(i){
  # i will be a row of idx, so i[[1]] has the first column and i[[2]] the second
  dx <- abs(df[i[[1]], "x"] - df[i[[2]], "x"])
  ymin <- min(df[i[[1]], "y"], df[i[[2]], "y"])
  dx * ymin
})
```

Then you can put everything together for subsequent analysis

```
output <- cbind.data.frame(idx, area = area)
head(output)
```

```
     1    2 area
1 var1 var2    1
2 var1 var3    2
3 var1 var4    3
4 var1 var5    4
5 var1 var6    5
6 var1 var7    6
```